# Moving Text Along with Shape in RaphaelJS Free Transform tool

Tags: svg, raphael

Am trying to create a sample shape(for eg, square) and use RaphaelJS Free Transform plugin to drag ,rotate or resize the shape.Now,I also want a text to be displayed in the center of the shape. Can anyone help me with transforming the text when the shape is transformed.

Comment: JsFiddle -https://jsfiddle.net/0nrechpw/1/

Comment: Only routes I can think of are using Snap.svg and groups, or editing the freetransform tool to include a callback option whenever it updates.